# How do I wrap elements inside the_content()?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using WordPress and CSS Grid to structure articles. The body text and headlines should be limited in width, images and other visual elements might grow to a full-width. I have solved this by specifying grid columns.

E.g. paragraphs with `grid-column: 5/11` and images with `grid-column: 1/15`. This works well, but I'm now dealing with a bunch of grid rows, as every paragraph becomes a new grid row. This makes highlighting content difficult, as well as aligning content next to the "main article" block.

**This is generated by the_content(); from WordPress.**

```
<h2>Headline</h2>
<p>Parahraph</p>
<p>Parahraph</p>
<p>Parahraph</p>

<div id="attachment_0001" class="wp-caption alignnone">
  <img src="#">
  <p class="wp-caption">Caption text</p>
</div>

<p>Parahraph</p>

<form>
   <input>
   <button>
</form>

<p>Parahraph</p>

<img src="#">

<p>Parahraph</p>
<p>Parahraph</p>
```

**But this is what I want it to be. Notice how everything except some elements are wrapped, including the h2 along with the p tags, and not one div for each element. But also excluding p tag captions.**

```
<div>
  <h2>Headline</h2>
  <p>Parahraph</p>
  <p>Parahraph</p>
  <p>Parahraph</p>
</div>

<div id="attachment_0001" class="wp-caption alignnone">
  <img src="#">
  <p class="wp-caption">Caption text</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Parahraph</p>
</div>

<form>
   <input>
   <button>
</form>

<div>
  <p>Parahraph</p>
</div>

<img src="#">

<div>
  <p>Parahraph</p>
  <p>Parahraph</p>
</div>
```

Any thoughts on how I can modify the_content(); to output the desired markup, or if there's another solution I can use – with CSS Grid?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you to use some content layout editor plugin instead (so only for the content, not the entire page). I usually code my own custom themes where it's all coded by me eccept for page contents (and only where and when needed). Currently, at least for me, the best (free) one is Elementor. Anyway these kind of layouts will be possible out of the box in the near future within native wordpress editor, when its Gutenberg editor will be finally released.

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to figure out some sort of "rule"/logic for where you want to insert divs or you should maybe look for a different solution.

For example, you could filter `the_content`, and add a `<div>`:

- Before `<h2>` and `<p>`
- Except where a `<p>` is preceded by a `</p>` or a `</h2>`

Add a `</div>`:

- After a `</p>` except where it is followed by a `<p>`

Then you need to double-check that it works, and maybe throw an error if the number of `<div>` and `</div>` do not match for some reason. If they do not match, your logic and exceptions may not be robust enough for the content.